# Java Sudoku Solution Verifier

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods, boolean

I am currently attempting to create a Java program that reads 81 integers (1-9) into an 9 X 9 matrix, and then tests to see if that matrix is a solution to a Sudoku puzzle. The parameters for a Sudoku solution are as follows: each number (1-9) must be represented in every row, column, and 3x3 square without any repetition in these areas. I have written a method to verify that the parameters are met for all rows and columns, however, I am struggling with coming up with an algorithm to verify the squares. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class SudokuCheck
{
  public static boolean sudokuCheck(int[][] s)
  {
    for(int row=0;row<9;row++)
      for(int col=0;col<8;col++)
      if(s[row][col]==s[row][col+1]){
      return false;}
     //Verifies rows

    for(int col2=0;col2<9;col2++)
      for(int row2=0;row2<8;row2++)
      if (s[row2][col2]==s[row2+1][col2])
      return false;
    //verifies columns

    return true;    
  }


  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] solution = new int [9][9];
    System.out.println("Enter the values of a 9 X 9 Sudoku solution");

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
      solution[i][j]=input.nextInt();
    //read values into matrix


    if(sudokuCheck(solution)==true)
      System.out.println("The entered 9 X 9 grid is a solution to a Sudoku puzzle.");
else
  System.out.println("The entered 9 X 9 grid is not a solution to a Sudoku puzzle.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is an example of a proper solution: int[][] solution =          {{4,2,9,8,1,3,5,6,7},
 {5,1,6,4,7,2,9,3,8},
 {7,8,3,6,5,9,2,4,1},
 {6,7,2,1,3,4,8,5,9},
 {3,9,5,2,8,6,1,7,4},
 {8,4,1,7,9,5,6,2,3},
 {1,5,8,3,6,7,4,9,2},
 {9,3,4,5,2,8,7,1,6},
 {2,6,7,9,4,1,3,8,5}};

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms

Comment: Here's a hint. Write a function that checks a 3x3 matrix for duplicates. Then you can call that 9 times from your main method with the appropriate subsections of your puzzle

Comment: I looks like your row and column checker have problems too.  You are only checking that adjacent cells are not equal in the row or column.  So you could pass with the same value twice on a row that are not next to each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can probably be optimized but following your approach

```
// row checker
for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
   for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
      for(int col2 = col + 1; col2 < 9; col2++)
         if(s[row][col]==s[row][col2])
            return false;

// column checker
for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
   for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
      for(int row2 = row + 1; row2 < 9; row2++)
         if(s[row][col]==s[row2][col])
            return false;

// grid checker
for(int row = 0; row < 9; row += 3)
   for(int col = 0; col < 9; col += 3)
      // row, col is start of the 3 by 3 grid
      for(int pos = 0; pos < 8; pos++)
         for(int pos2 = pos + 1; pos2 < 9; pos2++)
            if(s[row + pos%3][col + pos/3]==s[row + pos2%3][col + pos2/3])
               return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[][] f = {{4,2,9,8,1,3,5,6,7}, {5,1,6,4,7,2,9,3,8}, {7,8,3,6,5,9,2,4,1},
                 {6,7,2,1,3,4,8,5,9}, {3,9,5,2,8,6,1,7,4}, {8,4,1,7,9,5,6,2,3}, 
                 {1,5,8,3,6,7,4,9,2}, {9,3,4,5,2,8,7,1,6}, {2,6,7,9,4,1,3,8,5}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));
    System.out.println(checkBlock(f, 2, 2));
}

public static boolean checkBlock(int[][] f, int z, int s) throws Exception {
    boolean[] mark = new boolean[9];
    boolean res = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            int v = f[z * 3 + i][s * 3 + j];
            if (v == 0) {
                res = false;
            }
            if (mark[v - 1]) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            mark[v - 1] = true;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SudokuVerify {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2 },
                { 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8 }, { 1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7 },
                { 8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3 }, { 4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1 },
                { 7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6 }, { 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4 },
                { 2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5 }, { 3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9 } };
        boolean flag = true;
        int ExpectedVal = (1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 8 ^ 9);
        int ActualVal = 0;
//---># Checking for row Validation**
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            ActualVal = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                ActualVal ^= arr[row][col];
            }
            if (ActualVal != ExpectedVal) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
//---># **Checking for col Validation**
        if (flag) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
                ActualVal = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                    ActualVal ^= arr[col][row];
                }
                if (ActualVal != ExpectedVal) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
//---># **Checking for inside box Validation**
        if (flag) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {

                if (flag) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3) {
                        ActualVal = 0;
                        for (int ii = i; ii < (i + 3); ii++) {
                            for (int jj = j; jj < (j + 3); jj++) {
                                ActualVal ^= arr[ii][jj];
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        if (ActualVal != ExpectedVal) {
                            flag = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else
                    break;

            }
        }
        if (flag)
            System.out.println("Passes");
        else {
            System.out.println("Faied");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ^ is XOR operation

xor is commutative: A ^ B = B ^ A
xor is associative: (A ^ B) ^ C = A ^ (B ^ C)
xoring with zero does nothing: A ^ 0 = A
xoring something twice removes it: A ^ A = 0

if some duplicates in  values it will differ from the Actual value which is 1^2^3^4^5^6^7^8^9

So Code checking is it matching for row wise, column wise and 3 x 3 box wise (Condition for Sudoku Table)